# How to make a neural network for chess?

Tags: neural-network, chess

For my 10th grade 'personal project' (AP MYP thing) I am making a chess engine that uses many techniques to try and find the move that human players of different strengths would be most likely to play in a position.

One of these methods will be a neural network, and I have never made anything like that before, so I need some help.

First of all, I am not sure what my inputs need to be. In order to input the position, will I need to go as far as 385 nodes (6 pieces * 64 squares (-1 for black, 1 for white, 0 for empty) + whose turn it is (-1 or 1)), or can I do it in less? 65 nodes, with numbers from -6 to 6 for pieces?

Furthermore, I don't know how I will be able to code the output. How do I get it to pick from a list of possible moves, when the moves and even the amount of moves will always be different?

In short, I have absolutely 0 idea what to do and really need help.

Thank you very much if you have any advice!

Comment: Sorry, but if you have never worked with e.g. NNs, you should learn about them way before starting to do chess. Note that AIs for chess are not easy to implement, yu may choose a simpler idea to do your project about.

Answer (score 1):

This question is rather too broad for StackOverflow, but I'll provide some general hints.

Starting from where you are, the task you describe is non-trivial and likely to be many months of work. One good approach is to look at some open-source code like [Rubichess](https://github.com/Matthies/RubiChess) to understand how the [author](http://www.talkchess.com/forum3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=75016) fused [Stockfish](https://stockfishchess.org/) with some [neural networks](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Neural_Networks) to create a very strong chess engine. This will give you an idea of the techniques (and complexity) involved. Also read all of the links in the [chess programming wiki](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Main_Page) article on [efficiently-updatable neural networks](https://www.chessprogramming.org/NNUE).